Batch uploading rasters to PostGIS, slows way down
Problem (or at least I think it is a problem): If I set the raster folder to include 3 or 4 GeoTIFFs of ~ the same size and the 1st one uploads in 30 minutes, why would the next one take 90 minutes?
*This problem only seems to exist with raster > 5GB.
Info:
I have 48 varying size GeoTIFFs.  They are slope rasters of each state.  So naturally the smaller states are mostly < 1GB while some of the larger states are ~ 15 - 28GB.
I have had success in batch uploading the smaller states and even some of the mid size states.
However, I think something is wrong in my script or I am just not efficiently setting parameters.  I am new to PostGIS and programming all together so I have leaned heavily on AI to help with the programming and .conf settings.
Can anyone spot an obvious issue?  I know I do not have the SRID set, but the rasters are all in the correct projection and when I access them via QGIS or run SQL in pgAdmin, they have the correct spatial ref.
.conf settings I have changed
shared_buffers = 16GB
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB
checkpoint_timeout = 60min
max_wal_size = 5GB
min_wal_size = 80MB
Here is my main function
def upload_raster(raster_path, table_name):
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(raster_path):
            raise FileNotFoundError(f"Raster file does not exist: {raster_path}")


        raster2pgsql_command = [
            f'"{raster2pgsql_path}"',  # Include quotes to handle spaces in path
            "-I",  # Create spatial index
            "-C",  # Apply raster constraints
            "-M",  # Analyze after loading
            "-t", "256x256",  # Tile size
            f'"{raster_path}"',  # Include quotes to handle spaces in path
            table_name,
        ]

        # Pipe the output of raster2pgsql to psql
        psql_command = [
            f'"{psql_path}"', "-q", "-d", database_name, "-U", database_user, "-h", database_host
        ]

        print(f"Running raster2pgsql command: {' '.join(raster2pgsql_command)}")
        print(f"Running psql command: {' '.join(psql_command)}")

        process = subprocess.Popen(
            " ".join(raster2pgsql_command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True
        )
        with subprocess.Popen(" ".join(psql_command), stdin=process.stdout, shell=True) as psql_proc:
            stdout, stderr = psql_proc.communicate()
            if psql_proc.returncode != 0:
                raise Exception(f"psql error: {stderr.decode('utf-8')}")

        filename_column_command = [
            f'"{psql_path}"', "-d", database_name, "-U", database_user, "-h", database_host,
            "-c", f'"ALTER TABLE {table_name} ADD COLUMN filename TEXT; UPDATE {table_name} SET filename = \'{os.path.basename(raster_path)}\';"'
        ]
        subprocess.run(" ".join(filename_column_command), check=True, shell=True)

        vacuum_command = [
            f'"{psql_path}"', "-d", database_name, "-U", database_user, "-h", database_host,
            "-c", f'"VACUUM ANALYZE {table_name};"'
        ]
        subprocess.run(" ".join(vacuum_command), check=True, shell=True)

        print(f"Uploaded raster to table: {table_name}")
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to upload raster {raster_path}: {e}")
        return False

def upload_all_rasters():
    slope_rasters = [f for f in os.listdir(raster_folder) if f.endswith(".tif")]

    for raster in tqdm(slope_rasters, desc="Uploading Rasters"):
        raster_path = os.path.join(raster_folder, raster)
        state_name = raster.replace("slope_", "").replace(".tif", "").strip()
        state_abbreviation = state_abbreviation_map.get(state_name)

        if state_abbreviation is None:
            state_abbreviation = state_name.replace(" ", "_")
            notification_subject = f"Raster Upload Using Full State Name: {state_abbreviation}"
            notification_body = f"Abbreviation not found for state '{state_name}', using full state name for the table name."
            send_notification(subject=notification_subject, body=notification_body)

        table_name = f"slope_{state_abbreviation}"

        success = upload_raster(raster_path, table_name)

        if success:
            send_notification(
                subject=f"Raster Upload Successful: {table_name}",
                body=f"The raster {raster} was successfully uploaded to table {table_name}."
            )
        else:
            send_notification(
                subject=f"Raster Upload Failed: {table_name}",
                body=f"The raster {raster} failed to upload to table {table_name}. Check the logs for details."
            )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    upload_all_rasters()



What if you do the rasters in the other order? Is the 90 minute one 30 minutes?

Yes, it sure is, even if I do one and then manually go in and load the next, uploading time still increases.  I'm starting to see that the time it takes to complete either a time or wal checkpoint is around 80-90% of the checkpoint interval time.  So basically when a checkpoint is complete there is around 4 or 5 minutes of pure upload time before the checkpoint begins again.
